# Is there a more elegant way to format MySQL results in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I just asked myself, after a few years of development, if there is a more elegant way of formatting MySQL results into associative arrays like the one below.

Here some dummy code that shows how I usually do it.

```
$sql = 'SELECT field1, field2 FROM sample_table';
$res = $db->prepare($sql)->getAll();
$formatted = array();

foreach ($res as $row) {
    $formatted[$row['field1']] = $row['field2'];
}
```

As I'm doing things like these super often, I asked myself if there is a more elegant or quicker way.

Thanks!

Comment: Create objects which can be instantiated or easily populated with e.g. a `read_result_row($row)` function and let them handle the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to handle the recurring tasks. The idea is to encapsulate the
behaviors that you can reuse later with the minimum amount of code. Here's a basic example.
Keep in mind that you may want to delegate the database stuff (connection, queries, etc.)
to another class. Also keep in mind that this class is specific to an array with key-value
pairs (to be use with a query with 2 columns).

```
<?php

//Takes a two columns SQL query and format it to optain an array with key-value pair
class queryToMap{

    private $formattedArray = array();  //The formated array


    //Execute the query and format the array
    public function executeQuery($sql){

        $res = $this->dbQuery($sql);

        while($row = $res->fetch_array()){

            $this->formattedArray[$row[0]] = $row[1];

        }
    }

    //Returns the formated array
    public function getArray(){
        return $this->formattedArray;
    }

    //Execute query and return the result
    private function dbQuery($sql){
        //DB connection...
        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "bob", "123", "db");


        //if the query is based on user input, better use prepared statement 
        $res = $db->query($sql);

        return $res;
    }


}


//Use of the class
$a = new queryToMap();
$a->executeQuery("SELECT F_CUST_ID, F_CUST_NAME FROM TP_CUSTOMER");

//Output the array
var_dump($a->getArray());
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre! I was thinking about that, though this approach isn't dynamic for me enough. I thought that maybe there is some native support of doing that easier, but probably there isnt! (: